# PHP NTLM authentication

Tags: php, apache, ntlm

I am working on a NTLM authentication and i want use my Windows Session (Username and password) to access to my application;

I tried this Login script but they cannot successfully check userName/password validity:

```
<?php

$headers = apache_request_headers();
if (!isset($headers['Authorization'])){
    //spécifier l'en-tête HTTP
  header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
  header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM');
  exit;
}
$auth = $headers['Authorization'];
//echo $auth;
if (substr($auth,0,5) == 'NTLM ') {
  $msg = base64_decode(substr($auth, 5));
  if (substr($msg, 0, 8) != "NTLMSSP\x00")
    die('error header not recognised');
  if ($msg[8] == "\x01") {
    $msg2 = "NTLMSSP\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00".
        "\x00\x00\x00\x00". // target name len/alloc
      "\x00\x00\x00\x00". // target name offset
      "\x01\x02\x81\x00". // flags
      "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00". // challenge
      "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00". // context
      "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"; // target info len/alloc/offset
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM '.trim(base64_encode($msg2)));
    exit;
  }
  else if ($msg[8] == "\x03") {
    function get_msg_str($msg, $start, $unicode = true) {
      $len = (ord($msg[$start+1]) * 256) + ord($msg[$start]);
      $off = (ord($msg[$start+5]) * 256) + ord($msg[$start+4]);
      if ($unicode)
        return str_replace("\0", '', substr($msg, $off, $len));
      else
        return substr($msg, $off, $len);
    }
    $user = get_msg_str($msg, 36);
    $domain = get_msg_str($msg, 28);
    $workstation = get_msg_str($msg, 44);

    print "Invalid Windows Session :  $user from $domain/$workstation";
  }
}

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello Ez, Did you managed to make it works ?